# list.RemoveAt in loop

Tags: c#, list, loops

```
for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; ++j )
{
     if (list[j].current_status == false)
     {  
       list.RemoveAt(j);  
     }  
}
```

I want to remove all the items which has current_status == false in the list, However,
When execute the statement: list.RemoveAt(j), the list.Count will minus one. Finally, the original loop can not be looped from list[0] to list[list.Count]. How can I deal with this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int size = list.Count;
for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j )
{
   if (list[j].current_status == false)
   {  
      list.RemoveAt(j);  
      size--;
      j--;
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `RemoveAll` instead of `RemoveAt`:

```
list.RemoveAll(item => item.current_status == false);
```

Comment: This is much better than the original loop idea because it runs in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

Also running linear time, a reverse loop like so:

```
for (int j = length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
{
    if (!list[j].current_status)
    {  
        list.RemoveAt(j);
    }
}
```

Side note : try not to test booleans with "==" and/or "!=" but use the expression itself or the negation symbol is needed